# How to create polygons with a set area in MapInfo?

Tags: mapinfo, area, polygon-creation

I need to create polygons with set areas in MapInfo. There is a solution for QGIS in the form of the [the QAD plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qad/) but I can't find an equivalent tool for MapInfo.

The task I'm actually trying to do is create polygons which are e.g. 10% the size of an existing polygon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the MapCad tools (should be included in the Tool Manager) for this, there is a scale function. Once the tool is loaded, go to Spatial > Modify > Scale and then click on the object you want to scale (make sure the layer is editable). If you want 10% then enter 0.1 as the scale factor.